# Making a dynamic column line graph

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a graph where the number of columns varies. what I have done is used name manager to label each of the possible columns (1-100). I have then used these named ranges to create a graph.

Each column in the table should be identified as a series, the issue is that I do not know how to change the number of series automatically, so that when data is added to the column the chart automatically added the series in. I tried to do this by naming the range as a table, this also did not work as it included the empty columns as series on the chart.

the data I am trying to use is as follows;

[image: Data set]

When I add data to another column I want to add that series to the graph. Is there a way of doing this? because all I have been able to find are examples where the number of rows are the only thing that is dynamic.

Comment: Since you had been able to find are examples where the number of rows is dynamic, then you can just transpose this data using the transpose function or copy > paste special : transpose.. Then apply your learnt techniques. ( :

Comment: Unfortunately I need both rows and columns to be dynamic :(

Comment: mind sharing the reference for the "dynamic rows" solution ? (for learning/brainstorming purpose)

Comment: Pretty much just uses the INDEX or OFFSET functions, there are a number of videos online that show you how to do it with rows, I also managed to get the columns to work with the OFFSET function something like this but replace the 5 with another count function =OFFSET($D$2,0,0,COUNTIF($C$2:$C$100,"<> "),5) to count the number of cells that are not blank.